# Labels in GeoPDF using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, print-composer, geopdf

I have a problem with a vector layer in QGIS. When I export a print layout as geo-pdf and transfer it to a different device (whatsapp, email, etc), the labels of one specific layer as well as all other additional elements (legend, title, scale, etc) are mirrored, and are printed in a corner of the map.

I have tried:

- Literally all settings in the layout options: Different formats, resizing, replacing and modifying the labels, different pdf formats (it works when I rasterize it but then it becomes a very large file)
- I redrew the layer by hand, duplicated it, tried "fix geometries", added the labels as individual text elements in the layout mode, etc.
- Different transfer options to other devices (whatsapp, email, telegram, etc).
- I updated QGIS and started a new project from scratch.

I have not had this problem before in 4 years of working with QGIS.

[image]

[image: f]